# Correlation Coefficient between these two random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ is real-valued normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. What is the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $X^2$?

Comment: May I ask, if $\mu=0$, are $X$ and $X^2$ independent? I know their covariance is $0$, but this doesn't suffice.

Comment: Nope. They are not independent. [See here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/are-the-random-variables-x-and-fx-dependent/16342#16342).

Comment: @Zoe: Since $X^2$ is determined by $X$, they can't be independent unless $X$ is constant.

Comment: @Michael: That's not entirely true. You actually need $X^2$ to be constant, not $X$. :)

Comment: Also, I was mistaken in another respect: Adding a constant to $X$ has the effect of adding something other than a constant to $X^2$.  (And now I've deleted _that_ comment.)

Comment: ....but at any rate, for the _normal_ distribution, $X^2$ is constant only if $X$ is constant.

Comment: As a general idea, since $X^2$ is a quadratic function of $X$, their covariance is $0$ due to there is no linear relation between these two variables? As for the independence, it's like when they are independent, $f(X)$ tells no information about $X$, is that right?

Comment: And the above idea requires $\mu=E(X)=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an efficient way to deal with the numerator in the fraction that defines the correlation.
$$
\operatorname{cov}(X,X^2) = \operatorname{cov}\Big((X-\mu)+\mu,\  \  (X-\mu)^2 + 2\mu(X-\mu) + \mu^2\Big).
$$
Now we can throw away the "${}+ \mu$" and "${}+ \mu^2$" at the end and we have
$$
\operatorname{cov}\Big((X-\mu),\  \  (X-\mu)^2 + 2\mu(X-\mu)\Big).
$$
Then use bilinearity of covariances and this becomes:
$$
\operatorname{cov}(X-\mu, (X-\mu)^2) + 2\mu\operatorname{cov}(X-\mu,X-\mu)).
$$
This is
$$
0 + 2\mu\sigma^2.
$$
The first term is $0$ because the expected value of $X-\mu$ is $0$ and the distribution is symmetric about $0$.

Summary: $\operatorname{cov}(X,X^2) = 2\mu\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: You are trying to find:
$$\frac{E\left[\left(X^2-E\left[X^2\right]\right)\left(X-E\left[X\right]\right)\right]}{\sqrt{E\left[\left(X^2-E\left[X^2\right]\right)^2\right]E\left[\left(X-E\left[X\right]\right)^2\right]}}$$

For a normal distribution the [raw moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) are

- $E\left[X^1\right] = \mu$
- $E\left[X^2\right] = \mu^2+\sigma^2$
- $E\left[X^3\right] = \mu^3+3\mu\sigma^2$
- $E\left[X^4\right] = \mu^4+6\mu^2\sigma^2+3\sigma^4$

so multiply out, substitute and simplify.

Comment: I see the problem. When I was calculating the covariance, I mistook $E(X^2)=\sigma^2$, which led me to the wrong solution.

Comment: Therefore, the covariance should be $2\mu\sigma^2$.

Comment: Shouldn't the last term by $3\sigma^4$?

Comment: @Michael: Indeed it should - edited

Comment: @Zoe: Yes - as Michael Hardy shows in his answer

Comment: And I think the final answer should be $\mu\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{2\mu^2+\sigma^2}}$

Comment: @Henry, Yes I think so.